# @ImportResource path in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-config

I have a Spring-Datasource.xml file in /WEB-INF path. I want to import it in AppConfig.java that it is a config file. what is the correct path in  @ImportResource in NetBeans IDE? I coding in Spring MVC. I know that I should  use:

```
@ImportResource(classpath:Spring-Datasource.xml)
```

But it doesn't work.
Project Hirearchy:

```
-FinalWebStore
   -Web Pages
     -WEB-INF
          +views
          web.xml
          mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
          Spring-Datasource.xml
   -Source Packages
      +com.karans.finalwebstore.controllers
      +com.karans.finalwebstore.daoimps
      +com.karans.finalwebstore.daos
      +com.karans.finalwebstore.models
   +Dependecies
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WEB-INF directory path is not available in classpath in a Spring project.Move the file to src/main/resources and import it as follows:

```
@ImportResource(classpath:Spring-Datasource.xml)
```

Comment: What is exactly classpath?

Comment: What if we want to specify a custom path to the beans xml file?? How do we set the "classpath" that gets used by @ImportResource??

Answer (score 0):

Classpath it is `src/main/resources` and if your file is there, then will be right `@ImportResource("classpath:SpringDatasource.xml")`